# How to hide third element with same class

Tags: css, class

Using one css code i want to hide 'li' element with 'C' text from both the code.

I tried

```
.header.links .nav.item:nth-child(3)
{display:none!important;}
```

But its not working

```css
.header.links .nav.item:nth-child(3) {
  display: none!important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="header links">
  <li class="greet welcome" data-bind="scope: 'customer'"> </li>
  <li class="nav item">A</li>
  <li class="nav item">B</li>
  <li class="nav item">C</li>
  <li class="nav item">D</li>
  <li class="nav item">E</li>
</ul>
```

**Expected answer** should be
A
B
D
E

Comment: Actually the "c" is in 4th poistion.. so change the child(3) to child(4)

Comment: `.nav.item + .nav.item + .nav.item { display:none; } .nav.item + .nav.item + .nav.item + .nav.item { display: list-item; }` would work in theory, but whether that’s “nice” is probably a different matter …